# Notepad++ search by ignoring whitespace?

Tags: full-text-search, notepad++, whitespace

Dreamweaver has a very convenient search option at its "**Find and Replace**" dialog called "**Ignore whitespace**".

By checking that, you can find the same text no matter how many new lines, tabs or spaces you add or remove. All these variations below are the same text:

```
search for me please
```

(adding some blank spaces)

```
search             for me please
```

(adding a new line)

```
search             for me 
please
```

How can I search with Notepad++ while ignoring all the whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's quite not convenient to do that in notepad++.

1.You can Go to **Search -> Replace**

2.Select "Regular expression" under **Search mode**

3.Use \s* to replace space in your sentence for **Find what** and leave **Replace with** blank

4.Click **Find Next**

In your case, input "search\s*for\s*me\s*please" in **Find what**

'\s*' means any number (even 0) of whitespace characters. Whitespace characters include tab,space,newline and carriage return.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. That's a little something, although what I would like to do is to be able to simply type "search for me please" and match any of those variations. :/

Comment: @Louis if you're willing to learn a little bit of regex I think you'd find it really rewarding. It gives you all the power to perform that kind of search and more.

Comment: @JonM I'm familiar with regex. Thing is, with Dreamweaver I can just perform a search using clean, compact text (without the extra whitespace) and no matter how much more whitespace there is, it will find it. Imagine if I am searching for a huge block of code (let's say because of an online tutorial that suggests to search and find for a specific block of code). I can't possibly input regular expressions between all of the words, curly braces and whatnot! Right?